# Как сделать по клику на кнопку измение в таблице?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Второй день пытаюсь сделать на Jquery чтобы например на нажатие кнопки iPhone5 изменилась цена [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думал сделать замену просто по клику дивов но получаетя очень много таблиц для замены которые нужно прописывать в index.html(около 200строк). 
 Подскажите как решить даную задачу. Спасибо

```
        <section class="price">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="price_title">Прайс-лист на ремонт Apple</h2>
            <div class="price-btn">
                <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_1">iPhone 4</button>
                <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_2 active">iPhone 4s</button>
                <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_3">iPhone 5</button>
                <button class="price-btn_all price-btn-4">iPhone 5s</button>
                <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_5">iPhone 5c</button>
                <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_6">iPhone 6</button>
                <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_7">iPhone 6s</button>
                <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_8">iPhone 6s+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="price-container price-table_Iphone4s">
            <table class="price-table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <td>Услуга</td>
                <td>Время ремонта</td>
                <td>Наши цены</td>
                <td>Средняя цена по Самаре</td>
                <td>Ваша экономия</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Замена дисплея (копия высокого качества)</td>
                <td>от 100500 часа</td>
                <td>2 200&#8381;</td>
                <td>2 290&#8381; - 2 690&#8381;</td>
                <td>80-90%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Замена аккумулятора</td>
                <td>от 1 часа</td>
                <td>1 200 &#8381;</td>
                <td>1400&#8381; - 1500&#8381;</td>
                <td>30-40%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Замена задней крышки корпуса</td>
                <td>10 минут</td>
                <td>490&#8381;</td>
                <td>490&#8381; - 890&#8381;</td>
                <td>26-32%</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Прошивка</td>
                    <td>от 1 часа</td>
                    <td>500&#8381;</td>
                    <td>770&#8381; - 820&#8381;</td>
                    <td>31-46%</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ремонт после удара</td>
                        <td>от 1 дня</td>
                        <td>от 900&#8381;</td>
                        <td>1 290&#8381; - 1 690&#8381;</td>
                        <td>80-90%</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </tr>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Не знаю как у вас все устроено, но можно попбробывать такой вариант .Если таблица статическая задайте ячейкам с ценой классы. В js обьекте сохраните цены для каждого устройства и с помощью js/jquery помещайте их в нужный ячейки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам как то так у меня получилось https://jsfiddle.net/ecpmxtnv/32/

```
$(".price-btn_1").click(function() {
  $( "td:eq(6)" ).empty().append( document.createTextNode( "От 2часов" ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let Price = {
  iPhone4: ['2200', '1200', '490', '500', 'от 900'], // Важно чтобы елемент объекта соответствовал 'name' кнопки
  iPhone4s: ['2400', '1700', '350', '900', 'от 1200'],
  iPhone5: ['2900', '2000', '600', '1300', 'от 1500'],
  iPhone5s: ['3000', '2100', '900', '1350', 'от 1700']
};
let btn = document.querySelectorAll(".price-btn_all");
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function() {
    let arr = Price[this.name];
    let slots = document.querySelectorAll(".tablePrice");
    for (let i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
      slots[i].innerHTML = arr[i] + " " + '&#8381;';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="price">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="price_title">Прайс-лист на ремонт Apple</h2>
    <div class="price-btn">
      <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_1" name="iPhone4">iPhone 4</button>
      <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_2 active" name="iPhone4s">iPhone 4s</button>
      <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_3" name="iPhone5">iPhone 5</button>
      <button class="price-btn_all price-btn-4" name="iPhone5s">iPhone 5s</button>
      <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_5" name="iPhone5c">iPhone 5c</button>
      <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_6" name="iPhone6">iPhone 6</button>
      <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_7" name="iPhone6s">iPhone 6s</button>
      <button class="price-btn_all price-btn_8" name="iPhone6s+">iPhone 6s+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="price-container price-table_Iphone4s">
      <table class="price-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Услуга</td>
            <td>Время ремонта</td>
            <td>Наши цены</td>
            <td>Средняя цена по Самаре</td>
            <td>Ваша экономия</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Замена дисплея (копия высокого качества)</td>
            <td>от 100500 часа</td>
            <td class="tablePrice">2 200&#8381;</td>
            <td>2 290&#8381; - 2 690&#8381;</td>
            <td>80-90%</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Замена аккумулятора</td>
            <td>от 1 часа</td>
            <td class="tablePrice">1 200 &#8381;</td>
            <td>1400&#8381; - 1500&#8381;</td>
            <td>30-40%</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Замена задней крышки корпуса</td>
            <td>10 минут</td>
            <td class="tablePrice">490&#8381;</td>
            <td>490&#8381; - 890&#8381;</td>
            <td>26-32%</td>
            <tr>
              <td>Прошивка</td>
              <td>от 1 часа</td>
              <td class="tablePrice">500&#8381;</td>
              <td>770&#8381; - 820&#8381;</td>
              <td>31-46%</td>
              <tr>
                <td>Ремонт после удара</td>
                <td>от 1 дня</td>
                <td class="tablePrice">от 900&#8381;</td>
                <td>1 290&#8381; - 1 690&#8381;</td>
                <td>80-90%</td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
```